# Help finding a HP fanfic with a SS/HG pairing, where Hermione attends university at America

Tags: story-identification, harry-potter, fan-fiction

**What I remember:** Hermione's at university (I think at America), and people don't recognize her much. People don't believe that she even has a relationship or a love life at all. They won't even believe her that she knows Snape. Ergo, I believe (from what I remember was what motivated me to search through a ton of my favorited stories), was that her classmates don't even believe that she's friends with Harry Potter (they apparently know him) and Ron Weasley. Somehow, Hermione didn't get that famous at America. Or the newspapers left her out..

Her room mate is shocked, the entire dorm corridor was shocked when Severus came to visit her. I think he kissed her or hugged her or something. And it was enough to shock the entire dorm as I think Hermione's been refusing all the guys. Her room mate is somewhat slutty I think, if that helps. They don't get along at all. And I believe that the people there know Snape. I think from a potions-related uni-wide seminar or something.

**Where I think it is located:** Possibly The Petulant Poetess, Ashwinder Sycophanthex, or fanfiction.net (in order of likelihood of where it possibly exists according to my memory).

**Finished or Not:** I believe it was a WIP

**Date story was last updated:** I don't really remember, but I do remember that I've read it back in 2010.

**Why I need help:** I've been trying to find this back in 2011, and searched through my favorite lists. But I can't seem to find it, or have forgotten to favorite it.

Comment: A) This is a pretty common trope and pairing. B) This is pretty creepy and unpleasant and C) I'm fairly sure that their relationship borders on illegality. That said, is this it? https://www.fanfiction.net/s/10309545/1/One-Word - The publishing date appears to be 2014, but that's no indication where these things are concerned.

Comment: @Richard Hermione being at university at America, WHILE being unknown and ostracized isn't common I'm afraid. Uh no it isn't illegal, wizards in Harry Potter live normally well up to their 150s to 200s. Convert that ratio to human years so yeah. Nope sorry that isn't the story :) thanks for the help!

Comment: @ValCroft I completely don't understand the question. Can you edit the grammar and put whatever your question(s) are at the end of your post with a question mark after them? Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Is it Looking for Magic by Hypnobarb ? 
"Severus Snape and Hermione Granger deal with traumas past and present and find they have more in common than they realize as they prepare for the ultimate confrontation with Voldemort. SSHG pairing. Not HBP compliant. This is a novel length story."

Hermione  goes to an American University after Hogwarts. Technically incomplete but the last chapter posted is a good "end"
https://www.fanfiction.net/s/2737071/1/

Answer (score 1):

Is it Pen Pals by redfrog? https://www.fanfiction.net/s/3078673/1/Pen-Pals
She goes to uni in Australia tho but people didn't think she knew Dumbledore and Harry etc.

In https://www.fanfiction.net/s/1215092/7/Heart-over-Mind, Hermione goes to Trinity one of her roommates didn't like her.

Comment: Neither really fits, but you'll probably get the bounty  if yours is the only answer.

Comment: Which Trinity? Cambridge? Oxford? Dublin?

Answer (score 0):

It’s tea and sympathy by Jocemum.
What ur describing happens in the epilogue.

Comment: Can you provide relevant quotes?